# jquerymobile page content font not working

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I've been working with jquerymobile to build certain app, thing is I must use several font in content ... Roboto Black is used for `UI` like this

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto-Black';
        src: url('css/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf');
        }

body  * {
         font-family: "Roboto-Black" !important;
         color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
         font-size:12px;
         }
```

and that works just fine, but in few page contents I have some large text which is formated using several fonts, I have built css rules for divs in which is text, but its not working

css rule:

```
p.basic-paragraph {
                    font-family: "Minion Pro";
                    font-weight: normal;
                    font-style: normal;
                    font-size: 1em;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font-variant: normal;
                    text-indent: 0em;
                    text-align: left;
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    margin: 0em;
            }
span.no-style-override-2 {
                font-family: Roboto-Light;
                src: url('css/fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf');
            }
```

and page content html:

```
<p class="basic-paragraph basic-paragraph-override"><span class="no-style-override-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></p>
```

Comment: all the text in my app was roboto-black, and part of it needs to be roboto light, the parts I made css rules for

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Put your CSS inside a CSS file `your_css.css`, and make sure to define the fonts before:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-Black';
    src: url('./fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-Light';
    src: url('./fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf');
}

p.basic-paragraph {
    font-family: "Minion Pro";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-indent: 0em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0em;
}

span.no-style-override-2 {
    font-family: "Roboto-Light";
}
```

Include your CSS file, in your HTML file `your_html.html`, after your references to jQuery Mobile.

**Example:**

```
<html>
    <head>   
        <meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/test.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- PAGE 1 -->
        <div id="page_1" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">

                <p class="basic-paragraph basic-paragraph-override"><span class="no-style-override-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PS:** Pay attention to the path of your fonts, in your CSS file. The example above considers the following directory structure:

- `your_html.html`
- **css**

  - `your_css.css`
  - **fonts**

    - `Roboto-Black.ttf`
    - `Roboto-Light.ttf`